# issue with JQuery toggle

Tags: toggle, jquery

I think I typed the code right, but when it runs, `p` fades out *and* in. (the toggle is in tab %)

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/8Wv7M/3/)

Comment: you're gonna have to elaborate on your problem, this is a pretty vague question...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Wv7M/5/

Comment: Did you mean to use ` $('button').click(function () {
        $('p').fadeToggle('slow');
    });` Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pR4WZ/

Comment: You're calling `fadeIn`, then you're calling `fadeOut`.  The element is fading in, then it's fading out.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're calling this function directly after it.

```
$(function(){
    $('p').fadeOut();
});
```

Take a look at this.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Wv7M/8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine the fadeIn() method with the toggle() method. There is a method specific to combining toggle with fade: fadeToggle()

If you don't care about the fade effect, then nevermind had a working example above (comment 2).

[See this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jSK8B/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs').tabs();
    $('button').button();
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('p').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
```